# How to send your variable from page to page via the controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is the second time I have used CodeIgniter and there is one thing that does not succeeds. Sending a variable from my homepage to my header. This is my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['data'] = $this->BookModel->get_author();
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('home/index');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}
```

As you see, it's loading my `header`, my `index` and my `footer`.

This is my index file:

```
<?php
$title = "Books"; ?>    
<div class="content">
<table>
...
```

and this is my Header:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Author plaza</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css') ?>">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="website">
        <div class="header">
            <h1 class="kopje"><?php echo $title; ?> </h1>
            <img class="boekje" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/book.gif')?>"> 
        </div>
```

The variable `$title` needs to be printed using `echo` in the my `header` as a `H1`. For what I know is this the right way. But it won't work.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your defining the title below the header  so its not available in the header  what you need to do i define it in the controller and pass it to the views `$data['title']="Your Title"`

```
public function index()
{
    $data['data'] = $this->BookModel->get_author();
    $data['title]="your Header";
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('home/index',$data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}

in your view files you can access the key "title
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable is being used in the `Header` whilst it is declared only in `index`. You are trying to use the variable before it has been assigned.

Ideally this data should be in `BookModel` and then referenced from there.

Or, set the variable in the `Header` and then use it in `index`.

Comment: That's not the problem :p I commented it to view the error

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not passing it from controller?

```
$data['data'] = $this->BookModel->get_author();
$data['title'] ="Books";
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('home/index',$data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
```

In any view:

```
echo  $title;
```

Answer (score 0):

change `$data['data']` to `$data['titel']` in index function of your controller

Answer (score 0):

You can Use like this by sending seperate **$titel** variable
$data['titel'] ="titel";

```
<h1 class="kopje"><?php echo $titel; ?> </h1>
```

or
titel is in data variable you can use like this

```
<h1 class="kopje"><?php echo $data['titel']; ?> </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display custom title for different pages you should use controller to pass title to the view. In your code you are passing `get_author()` to the variable `$data['data']` so that you can use author data from your view using `$data` because you have passed `data` key in the `$data` array. Same as you can do it for title also like `$data['title'] = "Book Title"` using this statement you can print title on the page. By echoing `$title` on the view page

```
public function index()
{
    $data['data'] = $this->BookModel->get_author();
    $data['title'] = "Book Title"
    $data['what_ever_print'] = "Pass value from here and access from view like echo $what_ever_print"
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('home/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}
```

In the view you can print like this

```
<h1 class="kopje"><?php echo $title; ?> </h1>
```

OR If you want to print on the title tag you can do like below

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?> </title>
```